# Параллельные запросы к одному php скрипту в Apache

Tags: php, apache, parallel

Есть один php скрипт. В скрипте используются стандартные php сессии. Ситуация следующая: пользователь делает запрос к скрипту и пока он не отработает и не вернёт результат, все остальные запросы к этому скрипту будут ждать.

Каким образом мне настроить Apache, чтобы можно было делать бесконечное или лимитированное число запросов к одному скрипту, которые выполнялись бы параллельно и соответственно возвращали результаты независимо от того, когда и в какой последовательности были запущены?

PS Пробовал экспериментировать с Apache MPM c вот такими циферками:

```
KeepAlive Off
<IfModule prefork.c>
   StartServers        5
   MinSpareServers     5
   MaxSpareServers     10
   MaxClients          150
   MaxRequestsPerChild 3000
</IfModule>
```

Но это не работает или вообще не для этих целей...

Comment: А как вы пришли к выводу, что запросы ждут выполнения скрипта на уровне apache ? В любой конфигурации apache по умолчанию может одновременно работать несколько экземпляров одного и того же скрипта. Может скрипты запускаются и ждут уже внутри доступа к какому то общему ресурсу (например блокировки БД или еще чего похожего).

Comment: Я пришел к этому выводу, потому, что если в скрипте выполнить session_write_close() после session_start(), то скрипты могут отрабатывать параллельно. Затык именно в механизме сессий php или сервера.

Comment: сессии php к apache не имеют никакого отношения. копать надо в сторону php

Comment: ага, гугл сказал что php действительно блокирует файл сессии на время работы. Предлагают использовать другие движки сессий для php, которые позволяют не блокировать. https://ma.ttias.be/php-session-locking-prevent-sessions-blocking-in-requests/

Comment: https://beget.com/ru/articles/redis_session

Comment: Mike, оформите ответом, пожалуйста. Вопрос интересный.